# Get element from this array $scope.pricingList= [[Object { amount="1", type="HOURLY"}], [Object { amount="1", type="HOURLY"}]]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So far I have tried this:

```
if ($scope.flag) {
    $scope.partialPricing.push([$scope.p]);
    $scope.flag = false;
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.partialPricing.length; i++) {
        console.log("finding object = " + $scope.partialPricing);
        if ($scope.partialPricing[i].type != $scope.p.type) {
            $scope.partialPricing.push([$scope.p]);
            break;
        } else {
            console.log("Already Given . Please Clear .");
        }
    }

}
```

Problem is when it enters into the else condition, it gets 
`$scope.partialPricing = [Object Object]` and also, `$scope.partialPricing[i].type = undefined`.

My goal is to prevent user from giving same type twice. Here type is Hourly , Monthly , Weekly.

He can set the value only once. Tell me the solution or any other way i can do it?

Comment: What about your `$scope.flag` ? is it set to true or false by default ?

Comment: $scope.flag= true

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition in the loop won't work properly: it will add the element to the list if its type is different from the first element of the list, independently of all the rest of the list.

The easiest is to make a lookup function as follows:

```
function lookupByType(type) {
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.partialPricing.length; i++) {
     if ($scope.partialPricing[i].type == type) {
       return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
}
```

And then use it as follows (no for loop here):

```
if (lookupByType($scope.p.type)) {
  console.log("Already Given . Please Clear .");
} else {
  $scope.partialPricing.push($scope.p);
}
```

About `$scope.flag`, I assume you're aware that you use it to bypass the verification, you probably have a good reason for this. However, if the goal is only to insert the first element, there's no need for it: the lookup function will always return `false` if the list so far is empty.

**Edit:** You also had a type problem: your pricing list was an array of array of objects, and you used it as an array of objects. You probably want to use the latter, so you need to `push($scope.p)` rather than  `push([$scope.p])`.

Comment: Uh? You mean the line ` $scope.partialPricing.push($scope.p);` is never called? It should be. I'm assuming $scope is a global variable, maybe I'm wrong there?

Comment: can you help me using team viewer?

Comment: I don't know what is "team viewer", so I guess no I cannot help

Answer (score 0):

You may switch your else part a bit and check for equality, because that is what you need for exiting the loop. Then break and make your next action according of the check.

```
if ($scope.flag) {
    $scope.partialPricing.push([$scope.p]);
    $scope.flag = false;
} else {
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.partialPricing.length; i++) {
        console.log("finding object = " + $scope.partialPricing);
        if ($scope.partialPricing[i].type === $scope.p.type) {
            console.log("Already Given . Please Clear .");
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
         $scope.partialPricing.push([$scope.p]);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and perform a check

```
if ($scope.flag) {
    $scope.partialPricing.push([$scope.p]);
    $scope.flag = false;
} else {
    var found = false;
    if ($scope.partialPricing.some(function (price) { return price.type === $scope.p.type; })) {
        console.log("Already Given . Please Clear .");
    } else {
         $scope.partialPricing.push([$scope.p]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Below code may be helpful]

Why you need to push "$scope.P" into the partialPricing. Any logic related you handled this line?

$scope.partialPricing.push([$scope.p]);